# ParseObject objectIds are not showing up in my JSON response

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, json, razor

I initiate a task that queries a list of objects from my server.

**Yeet Object Class Structure (queried via Parse Dashboard API Console)**:

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "objectId": "6PgYUb6IUD",
            "notificationText": "yeeeeet!",
            "author": {
                "__type": "Pointer",
                "className": "_User",
                "objectId": "1RtqEgy1ct"
            },
            "replyCount": 1,
            "spice": 0,
            "repliedToBy": [],
            "likedBy": [],
            "createdAt": "2018-06-13T06:07:09.038Z",
            "updatedAt": "2018-06-13T22:27:36.636Z",
            "replyCount_str": "1",
            "yayeetedBy": [],
            "likesCount": 0,
            "likesCount_str": "0"
        }
    ]
}
```

Yeet extends ParseObject, which can be viewed here: https://gist.github.com/SeloSlav/0b8e4be6a8d11f6f235f2820220933e7

**Parse call (index.cshtml.cs):**

```
public IEnumerable<Yeet> Reeps { get; private set; }

public async Task<JsonResult> OnPostReeps()
    {

        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        Request.Body.CopyTo(stream);
        stream.Position = 0;

        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            string requestBody = reader.ReadToEnd();
            if (requestBody.Length > 0)
            {
                Reeps = await GetReepsAsync(requestBody);
            }
        }

        return new JsonResult(Reeps);
    }

private async Task<IEnumerable<Yeet>> GetReepsAsync(String yeetId)
    {
        var query = new ParseQuery<Yeet>()
                        .OrderByDescending("createdAt")
                        .WhereEqualTo("senderParseObjectId", yeetId)
                        .Limit(50)
                        .Include("author");
        Reeps = await query.FindAsync();
        return Reeps;
    }
```

**I then return the JSON results in my AJAX call (index.cshtml):**

```
console.log("Yeet ID: " + convoYeetId);
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Index?handler=Reeps",
            headers: {
                "XSRF-TOKEN": $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val()
            },
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: convoYeetId,
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(convoYeetId);
                console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
                ...
```

**And then print the results to my console:**

[image]

Yet none of the objects have an objectId.

I think `JsonResult` is interpreting the `IEnumerable<Yeet>` object that is being returned as a generic dictionary type, so the JSON it is generating is just a bunch of key-value pairs...

Comment: Can you post the class structure of Reeps object or confirm that there is no [ScriptIgnore] or [JsonIgnore] on the objectId

Comment: @KrishnanunniJeevan I posted it at the top of my post. How can I confirm  [ScriptIgnore] or [JsonIgnore] is not present?

Comment: @KrishnanunniJeevan Yeet extends ParseObject: https://gist.github.com/SeloSlav/0b8e4be6a8d11f6f235f2820220933e7